# How do I return the if statement value as the variable value(dday)?

Tags: swiftui

There is 2 variable. Variable day1 is bind to textfield, the variable 2 should has been a results of an if statement. the objective is to singularise a double digit no. e.g if the number is 16, the return will be  1+6 = 7, while 29 will gv me 2 + 9 = 11, then 1 + 1 = 2..  ultimately, every numbers will be singularise, and the computation should stop when the adding reach a single numbers.

I'm a beginner.

```
@State  private var day1 = ""
@State private var dday: Int??

var day2: String {
    let day4 = day1.prefix(1)
    return String(day4) }

var day3: String {
    let day5 = day1.suffix(1)
    return String(day5) }

var dayCount: Int {
    let dd1 = Int(day2) ?? 0
    let dd2 = Int(day3) ?? 0
    let dd3 = dd1 + dd2
    return dd3  }


var dC0: String {
let dc = String(dayCount)
return dc }

var dayCount1: Int {
    let dc1 = dC0.prefix(1)
    let dc2 = dC0.suffix(1)
    let dc3 = Int(dc1) ?? 0
    let dc4 = Int(dc2) ?? 0
    let dc5 = dc3 + dc4
    return dc5 }


var body: some View {

    VStack {
        TextField("day", text: $day1).keyboardType(.numberPad).frame(width: 70, height: 20).padding().background(Color.gray).cornerRadius(15).padding().font(.largeTitle)
    
        Text("\(dayCount1)").font(.title).fontWeight(.heavy).padding(3).frame(width: 70, height: 20).padding().background(Color.gray).cornerRadius(15).padding()

        if dayCount > 9 { Text("\(dayCount1)")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)} else {Text("\(dayCount)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)}
        

    }
        
   
}

    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's your code doing. From you answer it seems like you need to get sum of digits of the number, and if this sum has more than one digit - repeat that operation, until only one digit left. You can do it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var day1 = ""

    private var sum: String {
        var string = day1
        // repeat while number of digits is greater than 1
        while string.count > 1 {
            let sum = string
                // convert string to list of Int digits
                .compactMap { $0.wholeNumberValue }
                // sum them
                .reduce(0, +)
            // convert sum back to string
            string = String(sum)
        }
        return string
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            TextField("day", text: $day1).keyboardType(.numberPad).frame(width: 70, height: 20).padding().background(Color.gray).cornerRadius(15).padding().font(.largeTitle)

            Text("\(sum)").font(.title).fontWeight(.heavy).padding(3).frame(width: 70, height: 20).padding().background(Color.gray).cornerRadius(15).padding()
        }
    }
}
```